# Copy sheets after defined sheet to individual files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split my file into individual files to be copied in the same path. The VBA macro should split all sheets. The Macro should begin with the first sheet after a defined sheet (e.g. "Test").

I try to find a solution to define a sheet to start with, but without success.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet.Index` to identify the sheets to be copied, something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Splitbook()
    Dim xPath As String
    xPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = .Worksheets("Test").Index + 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            .Worksheets(i).Copy
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & .Worksheets(i).Name & ".xlsx"
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Next
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a worksheet.index function. Enter the name of your worksheet, get its index and then take only indexes greater than the one you want to start with.

```
dim wks as worksheet
dim startindex as integer
startindex = 0
for each wks in thisworkbook.worksheets
    if wks.name = "targetsheet" then
        startindex = wks.index
    end if
    if not startindex = 0 then
        if wks.index > startindex then
            'do some stuff
        end if
    end if
next
```

I have no clue what will happen if you are constantly changing the order of the sheets.

Edit: That was an easy test, it immediately reindexes upon moving so make sure they are in the proper order.